# Get values from multiple inputs with the same name. c# .net

Tags: c#, .net

I have this html form:

```html
<form method="post" action="/Record">
    <input type="text" name="items[0][name]" value="Watch" />
    <input type="text" name="items[0][model]" value="Ballon" />

    <input type="text" name="items[1][name]" value="Shape" />
    <input type="text" name="items[1][model]" value="Bleu" />

    <input type="text" name="items[2][name]" value="Accessory" />
    <input type="text" name="items[2][model]" value="Hublot" />

    <input type="submit" value="SEND" />
</form>
```

I need to get the value of every item. i try something like this in c# .net

```cs
String[] myItems;
myItems = Request.Form.GetValues("items");

foreach (var singleItem in myItems)
{
    WriteLine(singleItem.name);
    WriteLine(singleItem.model);

    WriteLine(singleItem["name"]);
    WriteLine(singleItem["model"]);
}
```

i appreciate your advice

Comment: Why dont you assign an Id to each input and then iterate over the inputs by Id?

Comment: Create a class that reflects your forms inputs (a model)

Answer (score 1):

let try as below:

```
var myItems = Request.Form["items"];
```